# flex - vertically align while using 0 0 30px

Tags: html, css

I'm using flex to horizontally lay out two items. I'm having trouble vertically aligning the two items though.  I'm looking to set the photo size as 28px or so.

What I'm looking for:

[image]

When the text takes up more than a single line:

[image]

but right now, it looks like this:

[image]

I wonder if this is because the image's original size is larger than 28px? justify content center didn't work.

```css
.sample {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sample .photo {
  flex: 0 0 28px;
}

.sample .text {
  font-size: 17px;
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sample img {
  width: 28px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample">
  <div class="photo"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/28x28/000/fff.png" alt="no picture"></div>
  <div class="text">sample text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include some sample HTML?

Comment: I did at the end.  Would you need more info?  <div class="sample">
      <div class="photo"><img src="img/sampleimg.jpg" alt=""></div> 
      <div class="text">sample text</div>
      </div>

Comment: can you clarify what's the expected/current behavior? can you add a jsfiddle/codepen link to play with the code?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. Note that it's always better to separate them using different code snippets.

Comment: @arieljuod  I've updated the post with current behavior. (already wrote desired behavior) https://jsfiddle.net/0nedo8uy/ - it's behaving a bit differently from my local copy, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add vertical-align:middle to sample img class

```css
.sample {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center; 
    }
     
    .sample .photo {
      flex: 0 0 28px;
    }
    
    .sample .text {
      font-size: 17px;
      flex: 1;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .sample img {
      width:28px;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="sample">
          <div class="photo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="no picture"></div> 
          <div class="text">sample text can sometimes get very long when we want to see how wrap works</div>
          </div>
```

Comment: weird - i reproduced it here https://jsfiddle.net/0nedo8uy/ and it's not working. also, on my local copy it looks really off (like in the original post)

Comment: here's an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9u1cL67w/

Answer (score 1):

You likely have some other CSS that's not been shared that's interfering with your code. Here's a different take on the problem: This simulates a more crowded area for the text using a "wrapper" element that mimics the gray-border box in the screenshots. Then the "sample" element top-aligns things so that the image and the first line of text stay on the same line. I added some padding and margin to keep the white space consistent.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sample {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.sample .photo {
  flex: 0 0 28px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.sample .text {
  font-size: 17px;
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sample img {
  width: 28px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sample">
    <div class="photo"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/28x28/000/fff.png" alt="no picture"></div>
    <div class="text">Sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this way... image parent div like "class= 'photo'" and the image was not same height because you have mentioned parent div(sample) flex css. The child div means (img tag) was not flex that's why it shows like that way...

```css
.sample {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.sample .photo {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
.sample .photo img {
display: flex;
}

.sample .text {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 100px)
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1070850/pexels-photo-1070850.jpeg" width="100%" height="auto" >
  </div>
  <div class="text">sample text</div>
</div>

<div class="sample">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1070850/pexels-photo-1070850.jpeg" width="100%" height="auto" >
  </div>
  <div class="text">sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using align-items css property on the container. When using flex the main axis (flex direction) is controlled with justify content and cross axis with align-items.

Comment: I did apply align items center to the parent item:  .sample {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
}